# Response body json contain escape string

Tags: c#, json, api

Right now I'm building an API using C#.NET, the API process the data then the result turned in json string form (not json object), but when i try to test using postman, the response body shown json data in escape string form.

My Code :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();    

NameValueCollection param;
string proc = InformationExtractor.request(Request, out param);
string json;
Process(proc, param, out json);

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);

return response;
```

Result :

```
"[{\"PK_Employee_ID\":1,\"Name\":\"test\",\"Age\":24,\"FK_Job_ID\":1,\"Created_Date\":\"2018-12-14T17:54:43.460\",\"LastUpdate_Date\":\"2018-12-14T17:54:43.460\"}]"
```

How to unescape the json result in response body ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here :

```
response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
```

You need to specify a response format (Encoding & MediaType) before returned it.

Try changing it into this :

```
response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```